# Unable to reach remote server from new ISP

Tags: windows, remote, isp, routing, traceroute

From my previous Internet Service Provider I was able to reach (ping/trace/remote desktop) my remote server (windows 2003). Since I changed ISP I cant reach it.

This is a `tracert` to the server from http://network-tools.com:

```
TraceRoute from Network-Tools.com to 190.167.228.38 [38.228.167.190.l.sta.codetel.net.do]
Hop (ms)    (ms)    (ms)             IP Address Host name
 1    0       0       0          8.9.232.73   xe-5-3-0.edge3.dallas1.level3.net  
 2    0       0       0          4.69.145.76      ae-2-70.edge2.dallas3.level3.net  
 3    1       1       1          4.68.63.226      ntt-level3-te.dallas3.level3.net  
 4    0       1       1          129.250.3.66     ae-6.r20.dllstx09.us.bb.gin.ntt.net  
 5    30      49      31         129.250.3.175    ae-2.r21.miamfl02.us.bb.gin.ntt.net  
 6    31      30      31         129.250.3.173    ae-2.r05.miamfl02.us.bb.gin.ntt.net  
 7    33      31      31         157.238.179.42   ae-0.codetel-verizon-dominicana.miamfl02.us.bb.gin.ntt.net  
 8    Timed out       Timed out       Timed out                -  
 9    Timed out       Timed out       Timed out                -  
 10       69      69      69         190.167.228.38   38.228.167.190.l.sta.codetel.net.do  
Trace complete
```

And this is the `tracert` from my pc:

```
Tracing route to 37.228.167.190.l.sta.codetel.net.do [190.167.228.37]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.0.2
  2     9 ms     9 ms     9 ms  host-190-106-241-1.supernet.com.bo [190.106.241.1]
  3    10 ms    10 ms    10 ms  host-190-11-79-1.supernet.com.bo [190.11.79.1]
  4    10 ms     9 ms     9 ms  host-200-58-68-198.supernet.com.bo [200.58.68.198]
  5    10 ms     8 ms     8 ms  host-200-58-68-197.supernet.com.bo [200.58.68.197]
  6   100 ms   103 ms   106 ms  176.52.253.189
  7   179 ms   131 ms   130 ms  176.52.251.77
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

I tried using google's public DNS 8.8.8.8 and didn't work.

**Is this something I could solve with a `rout add`?? what would be the routes to be added?**

Comment: nothing has changed on or by the remote server? firewall? router/switch changed?

Comment: absolutely nothing changed on the server... on my side i got a new router from the ISP

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your new ISP's router firewall. Turn it off and try to connect, if it works you found your issue.

Comment: Any luck?  I had this same issue and turning off the router firewall fixed it for me.

Comment: Nothing yet... I am now contacting my new ISP to create a complain ticket

Answer (score 0):

Give your ISP a call or log a ticket. Let they sort it out for you since they are your service provider.

Comment: Normally I'd be inclined to agree with you based on what he posed in the question, but it looks like based on his comment on it, he also got a new router.